# How to go back to the previous previous roughing in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How to navigate back twice in Angular?

I have a case user can navigate to view A and then to view B and then to view C and from view C the user can click on the browser back but instead of navigate to view B I want to navigate to view A.

Is there any option to do this in Angular? 
I'm using angular router.

Comment: Look at the [`replaceURL`](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#replaceUrl) option to `navigate`. You would use this when navigating from B to C.

Comment: @ofir i will posted my answer. hope this is the solution of your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
parent.history.go(-2);
```

Or

```
window.history.go(-2);
```